# Is there a function in Java that allows you to transform a string to an Int considering the string has chars you want to ignore?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a project for a Uni course where I need to read an input of an int followed by a '+' in the form of (for example) "2+".

However when using nextInt() it throws an `InputMismatchException`

What are the workarounds for this as I only want to store the int, but the "user", inputs an int followed by the char '+'?

I've already tried a lot of stuff including parseInt and valueOf but none seemed to work.

Should I just do it manually and analyze char by char?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Edit: just to clear it up. All the user will input is and Int followed by a + after. The theme of the project is to do something in the theme of a Netflix program. This parameter will be used as the age rating for a movie. However, I don't want to store the entire string in the movie as it would make things harder to check if a user is eligible or not to watch a certain movie.

UPDATE: Managed to make the substring into parseInt to work

```
        String x = in.nextLine();
        x = x.substring(0, x.length()-1);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: no. you'll need to "adjust" the String yourself, to make it into a parseable form, and then you can use Integer.parseInt(...)

Comment: Maybe you could just substring, and the parse

Comment: What about nextLine(), remove the last char since it's a + and just parseInt() from there ?

Comment: It's a pity there's no single API method for this. Even back in the 1970s in C you could simply do `scanf("%d+", &n)`.

Comment: I've tried doing a substring by removing the last element (the +) and then using the parseInt() and it still throws an InputMismatch

Answer (score 1):

Try out `Scanner#useDelimiter()`:

```
try(Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in)){
    sc.useDelimiter("\\D"); /* use non-digit as separator */
    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Input: `2+33-599`

Output:

```
2
33
599
```

OR with your current code `x = x.substring(0, x.length()-1);` to make it more precise try instead: `x = x.replaceAll("\\D","");`

Comment: Thanks for answering, but what's the "\\D" for?

Comment: @AntonioBC, its RegEx `\d` denotes digits(`0-9`) whereas `\D` non-digits

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll try it out in a bit and i'll get back to you!

Comment: Got the substring to work. I llocally store it as a string first, then substring it to remove the last char, then user parseInt. 
dont really know why it wasn't working at 1st

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should manually do it. The methods that are there will throw a parse exception. Also do you want to remove all non digit characters or just plus signs? For example if someone inputs "2 plus 5 equals 7" do you want to get 257 or throw an error? You should define strict rules.

You can do something like:  Integer.parseInt(stringValue.replaceAll("[^\d]","")); to remove all characters that are no digits.

Comment: The user will always input something like "10+" "1+" "7+". It's a parameter for an "age rating" for a movie (the theme of the project is to do something similar to Netflix). I want to store the rating as an Int only instead of a string since it'll be easier to compare to the age of the users and determine if they're eligible or not to watch a movie.

Answer (score 0):

Hard way is the only way!
from my [Git repo](https://github.com/optmzer/poker/blob/master/src/poker/Game.java) line 290.
Also useful [Javadoc RegEx](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
It takes in an input String and extracts all numbers from it then you tokenize the string with `.replaceAll()` and read the tokens.

```
        int inputLimit = 1;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        try{
            userInput = scan.nextLine();

            tokens = userInput.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            //get integers from String input
            if(!tokens.equals("")){
                for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length() && i < inputLimit; ++i){
                    String token = "" + tokens.charAt(i);
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(token);
                    if(0 == index){
                        return;
                    }
                    cardIndexes.add(index);
                }
            }else{
                System.out.println("Please enter integers 0 to 9.");
                System.out.print(">");
    }
```

Comment: The code I posted removes all non digits. It is from my Uni project where a user input an integer with either - or + or other non integer values like "a 3 + r" and it returns 3 as an `int`. It is tested and working code. Or check this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for inspiration. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions already have been given, Here is one more.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String numberWithPlusSign = sc.next();
String onlyNumber = numberWithPlusSign.substring(0, numberWithPlusSign.indexOf('+'));

int number = Integer.parseInt(onlyNumber);
```